# How to draw a mathematical graph on mac

Tags: macos, mac, graphics, graph

I want to draw two plots

1. at x=1, y=3, at x=2, y=9
2. change the above plot so that y=exp(y), x is unchanged.

I know this might seem silly to ask, but I do not have any experience to draw a mathematical plot. Is there any built-in app to do so? I'd be very appreciated for your help.

Comment: macOS includes [Grapher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapher). Try also [Desmos | Graphing Calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).

Comment: Heads up, grapher is in the Utilities folder in Applications...

Comment: @lhf I've checked Grapher. It seems to need a function, but I don't have any function here. Furthermore, I want to plot them as a bar chart

Comment: What does the exp mean in y=exp(y)?  Is that expression correct, or did you perhaps mistype it?

Comment: @TomGewecke It's the exponential function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:   Plotting just 2 points will give you a straight line only. To see any curvature in a date set, you must plot more than 2 points and the x values must span the proper region.

I think Excel, Numbers or Google Sheets would be your best bet. You can define an x range of values in one column and then calculate the y values. Both Excel and Numbers have charting/plotting capabilities. Be sure to select "scatter plot" as your choice for chart type. You can then plot the x and y data you generated. You can choose bar chart if that is what you want. Below is an image of your result using Google Sheets. If you change the x, y or y2 values the chart will update to reflect the new values. The image won't update though.

[image]

There are other plotting apps for the Mac. The Mac comes with Grapher which is good for charting functions. There is also [Magic Plot](https://magicplot.com), and [Veusz](https://veusz.github.io).  These are probably overkill for what you want which is why I recommended a spreadsheet package.